# Draw an image on-top of Progress View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, uiprogressview

I'm trying to create a custom UIProgressView and I want it to look like this:

[image: progressview]

But everything that I'm trying is not working (iOS7). I want it to support iOS5+ and also in iOS7. Finally I did something and I almost there, but I have few problems.

This is how it looks now:

[image: progressview]

How can I put the image behind the progress view it self, also, how can I change the color of the progress bar it self and how can I force it to stay on the margins of the image?

How can I change the frame of the progress view?

This is my code:

```
- (void)createProgressView
{
    //   NOT CHANGING THE FRAME
    self.packageUtilizingCellProgressView.frame = CGRectMake(105, 20, 91, 14);
    self.packageUtilizingCellProgressView.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyleBar;

    //   CHANGING THE FRAME
    [[UIProgressView appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(105, 20, 91, 14)];
}
```

I've also created a subclass of UIProgressView called MYProgressView and in drawRect I've added those lines:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_view_transparent_background.png"]];
    [background.image drawInRect:rect];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:background];
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I do it the right way?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: check this:- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIProgressView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to use a custom Progress View using [ImageProgressBar](https://github.com/martin-magakian/ImageProgressBar).
Create your custom progress bar and add a UILabel on top of it.

It support iOS5+ and iOS7